# How to get the exposure time of a camera when an images is clicked using opencv?

Tags: image, opencv, camera-calibration, hdrimages

Is it possible to get the exposure time of a camera when a photo is clicked.
In opencv at the time of video it can be set and get using CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE in Capture property function. But in case of images how how we can get it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For images, I would suggest to use lightweight [easyexif](https://github.com/mayanklahiri/easyexif) to extract the exposure time.

Example:

```
EXIFInfo result;
result.parseFrom(JPEGFileBuffer, BufferSize);
...
printf("Exposure time: 1/%d s\n", (unsigned) (1.0/result.ExposureTime));
```